# Applying custom CSS to individual ioslides

Tags: css, r, ioslides

I am just going to use the default data/presentation that one gets when you create a new ioslides presentation. If I wanted to modify only the second slide (## R Markdown), how would I set the css document so that it only dealt with that one slide and not the entire item? At the moment, keeping it simple so just changing the font size. But hoping to modify the header as well in time.

Currently, this is what I have in place

```
 R Markdown{
font-size:6 px;
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Just put together a simple document with two slides or something for testing.

Comment: MrFlick, It is the slide presentation that is produced when you click on File>new file>R Markdown and then you specify ioslides presentation. It uses the mtcars data set that comes with R

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer but it starts myself (and somebody else) on the right path. Below is what you will put in your R-markdown file. Again, this is the default ioslides presentation that comes with installing R Studio. the second part is the .css text that you will use.

```
  ## R-Markdown {#R-Markdown .emphasized}

  #R Markdown{
  color: blue;
  }

 .emphasized {
  font-size: 6px;
  margin:7px;
  }
```